# C++ bitshift causing issues to another variable

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I'm currently learning c++ and decided as a first project to make a wave file parser. I have the logic I want to get the ChunkSize, but for some reason the bit shifting for wav.ChunkSize causes the wav.ChunkID to append 2 extra characters at the end.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include "bwave.h"
#include  <cstdint>
using  namespace std;

bwave wav;

int main(){
    std::ifstream input("cello.wav", std::ios::binary);

    std::vector<uint8_t> buffer((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input)),(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

    for (int i = 0; i < 60 ; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Byte " << i << ": ";
        std::cout  << buffer[i] <<" ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    wav.ChunkID[0] = buffer[0];
    wav.ChunkID[1] = buffer[1];
    wav.ChunkID[2] = buffer[2];
    wav.ChunkID[3] = buffer[3];

    wav.Type[0] = buffer[8];
    wav.Type[1] = buffer[9];
    wav.Type[2] = buffer[10];
    wav.Type[3] = buffer[11];

    wav.DataStart[0] = buffer[36];
    wav.DataStart[1] = buffer[37];
    wav.DataStart[2] = buffer[38];
    wav.DataStart[3] = buffer[39];

    unsigned char tmp[4];

    // ChunkSize    
    for (int i = 4; i < 8 ; ++i)
    {
        switch(i){
        case 4:
            tmp[3] = buffer[i];
            std::cout << bitset<8>(tmp[3]) << "\n";
            break;
        case 5: 
            tmp[2] = buffer[i];
            std::cout << bitset<8>(tmp[2]) << "\n";
            break;
        case 6: 
            tmp[1] = buffer[i];
            std::cout << bitset<8>(tmp[1]) << "\n";
            break;
        case 7: 
            tmp[0] = buffer[i];
            std::cout << bitset<8>(tmp[0]) << "\n";
            break;
        default:
            printf("%s\n","Error!" );
            break;
        } 
    }

    std::cout << bitset<24>(tmp[0] << 24  | tmp[1] << 16 | tmp[2] << 8 | tmp[3] ) << "\n";

    wav.ChunkSize = tmp[0] << 24  | tmp[1] << 16 | tmp[2] << 8 | tmp[3];

    // Datasize
    for (int i = 40; i < 44 ; ++i)
    {
        switch(i){
        case 40:
            tmp[3] = buffer[i];
            break;
        case 41: 
            tmp[2] = buffer[i];
            break;
        case 42: 
            tmp[1] = buffer[i];
            break;
        case 43: 
            tmp[0] = buffer[i];
            break;
        default:
            printf("%s\n","Error!" );
            break;
        } 
    }
    //wav.DataSize = tmp[0] << 24  | tmp[1] << 16 | tmp[2] << 8 | tmp[3];

    std::cout << "Header: "    <<   wav.ChunkID << "\n";
    std::cout << "Size: "      <<   wav.ChunkSize << "\n";
    std::cout << "Type: "      <<   wav.Type << "\n";
    std::cout << "Data: "      <<   wav.DataStart << "\n";
    std::cout << "Data Size: " <<   wav.DataSize << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output of the following.

```
...
Byte 59:  
00101010
01100011
00001100
00000000
000011000110001100101010
Header: RIFF*c
Size: 811818
Type: WAVE
Data: data
Data Size:
```

Also i'm open to any suggestions for best practices.

Reference - http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/

Thank you for your time,
B

EDIT - The bwave file

```
struct bwave{
    char ChunkID[4];
    uint ChunkSize;
    char Type[4];
    char Format[4];
    uint NumChannels;
    uint SampleRate;
    uint BPS;
    char DataStart[4];
    char DataSize;
};
```

Comment: You're going to need to get that indentation under control. That conveys not only structure but intent, and what you have here is pretty chaotic.

Comment: _"Also i'm open to any suggestions for best practices."_ use a debugger

Comment: Instead of doing your own bit smashing to handle endian conversion, why not use a proven, working function?

Comment: Parsing sound files is a great project! Good luck for this!

Comment: Those `switch` statements are not needed. Just do `tmp[7-i] = buffer[i];`.

Comment: `bitset<24>(tmp[0] << 24  | tmp[1] << 16 | tmp[2] << 8 | tmp[3] )` is trying to put 32 bits into a bitset with only 24 bits.

Comment: `wav.ChunkID` is missing a null terminator.

Comment: Can you add the declaration of the `bwave` structure?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! Do I need a Null Terminator if I'm storing it as an array of chars instead of a string object? I ran the debugger and it seems my variable is in good shape, but the extra characters are still printing after it.

Comment: No you dont need to store the null terminator. But when you output your variable to the stream via the << operator that itself requires a null terminated c string (it has no overload for an array of 4 chars or anything like that)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my problem has been solved! I fixed it by giving my char array 1 extra byte than it needed. I think this worked, because C expects a null terminator and if it doesn't see one the memory does something wonkey. Like printing characters I didn't want. 
the fix in the end was as follows.

```
char ChunkID[4]; -> char ChunkID[5];
```

Thank you everyone for the help!